# Страница 404 на Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, spa, ui-router

Есть SPA на первом Angular. Используется ui-router. Есть страница с урлом, типа "/cities/32456". Когда открывается эта страница, из урла берется код города, отправляется на бекенд. С бекенда приходит либо инфа о городе, либо ошибка 404, если города с таким кодом в базе нет. В первом случае формирую страницу из полученных данных. Во втором мне нужно показать вьюху 404-ой страницы. Собственно, вопрос, как ее показать? У меня на таком урле уже висит шаблон страницы города. Как сменить его на лету на шаблон страницы 404?

Роутинг:

```
angular.module('cities')
  .config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state({
    name: 'city',
    url: '/cities/:id',

    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/city.html',
        controller: 'cityCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });

});
```

Контроллер:

```
  var id = $stateParams.id;

  $http.get('/api/cities/' + id).then(function(city){
    // Данные получены, формируем страницу
  }, function(err){
    // Проверяем, если код ошибки 404, значит города с таким айди в базе нет. Показываем страницу 404 (???)
  });
```

Comment: Какая версия angular?

Comment: Версия Angular 1.5.0

Comment: Первое что приходит в голову - сделать редирект на 404 страницу. Но это слишком очевидно. Почему тебе это не подходит?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы адрес остался прежним "/cities/32456".

Comment: А можно код, который касается вопроса? Есть небольшая идея, но сомневаюсь что она сработает.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавил код. Я понимаю, что запрос делать в контроллере не хорошо, но я сделал так для простоты примера.

Comment: Знаешь, я думаю, можно сделать отдельный вью на ссылку "/cities/32456/404" или "/cities/32456/not_found"

Comment: Этот вариант я оставил на случай, если так и не смогу найти ответ на свой вопрос. Но то, что я хочу сделать, задача по идее распространенная, хотелось бы все таки узнать, как это обычно делают.

Comment: данный запрос можно перенести в resolve роута, так как при 404 ошибке он будет reject, попадешь в обработчик события StateChangeError, в нем можно сделать редирект на 404 страницу, и поставить флаг - не менять текущий урл

Comment: А параметры `{location : false, relative : $state.current }` не помогут оставить адрес страницы прежним?

Answer (score -1):

Прописываешь роут без `url`

```
$stateProvider.state('404', { template: '<h1>Not found</h1>' });
```

Далее, в контроллере:

```
$http.get('/api/cities/' + id).then(function(city){
// Данные получены, формируем страницу
}, function(err){
  if(err.status === 404) {
    $state.go('404');
  }
});
```

Comment: *"Мне нужно, чтобы адрес остался прежним "/cities/32456""*. – user229442 6 часов назад

Comment: так он и останется

Comment: только роут должет быть **без url**

Comment: Спасибо! Это рабочий способ. Но с ним появляется проблема. Если со страницы 404 нажать браузерную кнопку "назад", юзер возвращается обратно на сломанную страницу

Comment: Тут уже нужно крутить в сторону **веб сервера**